# Process Builder Formula

Tags: formula, process-builder, process

I have to get the contact name and here are some requirements, Could Anyone help me how I can use formula for  this by process builder ?
Here

> Platform is a pick list ;
>
> Role is pick list;
>
> Business Unit is pick list

Contact Name = IF Platform contains AAA, then Contact associated to Opportunity with Contact Role contains "Primary Sales "
and does not contain Business Unit "BBB";

If no Primary Sales ,
then Contact associated to Opportunity with Contact Role contains "Primary Sales Contact" and does not contain "BBB"

Comment: whats the issue you are facing. Can you post whatever you have tried so far

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply, I tried to get the platform field of contact role object but I could not do it .